# Prevent Mutt send to default email address

Tags: linux, bash, email, mutt

I use the below command to send email with Mutt

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" Email -s "Hi, friends" xxx@gmail.com < temp.html
```

It successfully sends email to `xxx@gmail.com` but also sends to an other email address `yyy@gmail.com` which I do not specify. It is quite annoying. Would you show me how to avoid this problem?

In my `~/.muttrc`, I cannot find anything related to `yyy@gmail.com`. Here is my `~/.muttrc`:

```
set from = "my_email@gmail.com"
set realname = "My name"
set imap_user = "my_email@gmail.com"
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set header_cache =~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates
set smtp_url = "smtp://my_email@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "my app password"
set move = no 
set imap_keepalive = 900
set send_charset="us-ascii:utf-8"
```

Comment: Have you got anything in the temp.html file that may be misinterpreted as a yyy email address?

Comment: I have checked ```temp.html``` but it does not contain any information of ```yyy@gmail.com```. Hence, I think ```temp.html``` is not the source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Omit your third argument `Email`. It gets interpreted as a target email address, which then is completed using your own email domain.

On a side note: If the quote of your command is original, the not specified address should be *Email@gmail.com*.